# Spring MVC ConversionService Defaults

Tags: java, spring

I've written a ConversionService as below.  This works in converting my String to IMRM in the controller when I have an object that contains an IMRM.  However, I'm getting a bug in another place in the system.  Apparently, we haven't used Spring 3 ConvertorServices before (I'm registering the first one here.) and part of the system relied on whatever was the default before.  The area that has the problem looks like:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="a=b,c=d" id="a=b,c=d">
```

And this is bound to a List java object.  Before, this would be just a single object with the value "a=b,c=d" but now I'm getting two objects ["a=b", "c=d"].  This is a problem because it's not expecting this behavior and it breaks the old code here.

How can I get the ConversionService to use the old (PropertyEditor?  Not super sure how spring does this by default) way of doing this?  Or should I just register something to override this?  I'm open to ideas and I'm feeling stuck here.

Thanks!

Converter:
    final class StringToIMRM implements Converter {

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StringToIMRM.class);

@Override
public IMRM convert(String source) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(source, IMRM.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof JsonParseException || e instanceof IOException || e instanceof JsonMappingException) {
            LOG.error("Error converting String to IMRM object. source={}", source, e);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error converting String to IMRM object.", e);
    }
}
```

And this class:

```
public class ConversionServiceInitializer implements WebBindingInitializer {
    @Autowired
    private ConversionService conversionService;

    @Override
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) {
        binder.setConversionService(conversionService);
    }
}
```

Here's my XML setup.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="com.saasure.framework.web.bind.ConversionServiceInitializer"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And:

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.saasure.application.generic.setup.beans.StringToIMRM"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of the dark side of spring ... If you do not register any conversion service, it automatically does it and chooses a very nice, with a lot of default converters.

As soon as you register your own, it assumes you know why and does not add anything to your config ... and you have lost all the default converters !

So you should :

- first register what is spring default : a `FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean` (I found it through debugging ...) => fine you have all defaults converters !
- add all your converters to this one

In full XML config, it could look like :

```
<bean id="conversionService"
      class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
      p:targetObject-ref="conversionService" p:targetMethod="addConverter">
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value type="java.lang.Class">java.lang.String</value>
            <value type="java.lang.Class">package.to.IMRM</value>
            <bean class="com.saasure.application.generic.setup.beans.StringToIMRM"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If you do no like `MethodInvokingFactoryBean`, you can use a `Configuration` bean to do some java config, or make you converter an `IntializingBean` and register it in a `afterPropertiesSet`.

Comment: So true for 'the dark side of spring'

Answer (score 1):

Serge has a great response to this.  What I ended up doing was creating my own PropertyEditor (yes pre-spring 3) and adding it.  This worked out great!

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way to register custom converter:

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="registerDefaultFormatters" value="true" />
    <property name="converters">
        <bean class="com.saasure.application.generic.setup.beans.StringToIMRM" />
    </property>
</bean>
```